# NUL: Port Disappears

Tags: windows-7

On a Windows 7 64bit workstation, we've got a PDF printer driver set up on the NUL: port.  About once a week, the NUL: port just disappears which borks the PDF printing.

We can't find any clues to the cause.  We did notice that if the print spooler is stopped, the NUL: port disappears, but the spooler is always running after the user reports the problem, so this may or may not be related.

Any ideas what might be causing us to lose the NUL: port?

**Note:** This is for Amyuni PDF Converter.  They specify to install on NUL: port for Win 7 64bit.  It works fine for us on hundreds of other similar machines.  On the one machine that has problems it is due to the disappearance of the NUL: port.)

Comment: Why are you using `NUL:` for a printer?